# Running a Method Upon Exit Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C#/WPF application that consists of a mainwindow and a system tray icon. I have configured App.xaml with `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"` in order to keep the application running in the system tray upon closing the main window.

Now I'd like to associate a method to the click event of the "X" close button on the mainwindow that checks to see if an observable collection has any members and disallows the mainwindow close if the count > 0. I'm having trouble finding out how to run a method when the X button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a handler to the `Closing` event, which will get called when you try to close the window (including the X button).  Then after your checks, if you do NOT want the window to close, set your `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` to true.

```
private void OnWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (someCollection.Count > 0) e.Cancel = true;
}
```